# How am I getting this entropy calculation wrong?

Tags: entropy, information-theory

I am following the entropy calculation in 1a [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eawm/15781/2003/midterm2003-solution.pdf).
[image]

Shouldn't the solution for H(Edible | Odor = 1 or 3) be like this?

$H = -\frac{3}{6}\log_2{\frac{3}{6}} = \frac{1}{2}$

My reasoning is that we should only count the upper half that is edible.  The inedible lower half should be left out.  What is wrong with the reasoning?  Thanks.

Comment: Entropy is computed with respect to **all** values of a probability distribution. This means you compute entropy with respect to both edible and inedible events.

Comment: Possibly, the name of the variable is misleading you. Edible is the name of the variable and its values are Yes or No. If the problem were what the entropy of Gender, given some conditions, you wouldn't leave out the females. Also, your calculations are inconsistent, as you are dealing only with one term with probability 1/2.  Whatever the problem, your probabilities should sum to 1. You have two terms and they happen to be identical.

Comment: Thanks, gentlemen!  I was indeed misled by the variable name.